# The content doesn't rerender on the first sight in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, rerender

`My index.js file:`

```
import Post from "@/components/Post"
import Modal from "@/components/Modal"
import {useState} from "react"

export default function Home() {

  // States
  const [modalTitle, setModalTitle] = useState('Title')
  const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState('Content')
  const [modalShown, setModalShown] = useState(false)
  const [audioDeleted, setAudioDeleted] = useState(false)
  const showModal = (title, content) => {
    setModalTitle(title)
    setModalContent(content)
    setModalShown(true)
  }
  const hideModal = () => {
    setModalShown(false)
  }

  const ShowEditConfirmation = () => {
    showModal('Edit post?', <div>
      <button onClick={() => {setAudioDeleted(!audioDeleted)}}>
        { audioDeleted ? 'Undo' : 'Delete' }
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => {
        console.log(audioDeleted)
      }}>Apply Changes</button>
    </div>)
  }

  const posts = [
    {id: 1, file_type: 'audio', file: '/uploads/audios/LoveStory.mp3', date: '1 Hour ago'},
  ]

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <Modal modalShown={modalShown} hideModal={hideModal} title={modalTitle} content={modalContent} />
        <div>
          {
            posts.map((post, index) => {
              return <Post key={post.id} ShowEditConfirmation={() => ShowEditConfirmation(post)} />
            })
          }
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

`My modal.js file:`

```
const Modal = (props) => {
  const {modalShown, hideModal, title, content} = props

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={hideModal} className={`${modalShown ? 'fixed' : 'hidden'}`}></div>
      <div>
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <button onClick={hideModal}>&times;</button>
        <div id='modal-content' className="max-h-96 overflow-auto">{content}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

`and my post.js file:`

```
const Post = (props) => {
  const {ShowEditConfirmation} = props

  return (
    <article>
      <button onClick={ShowEditConfirmation}>Edit</button>
    </article>
  )
}

export default Post
```

When I click on `Edit` button which triggers the `ShowEditConfirmation`, this function triggers `showModal` that accepts `title` and `content` as its parameters. At the init point the value of `audioDeleted` is false so the `Delete` would be visible. The problem is when I click on the `Delete` button which triggers `setAudioDeleted(!audioDeleted)`, the value of `audioDeleted` won't change. And when I click on `Apply Changes`, the value of `console.log(audioDeleted)` is false. And when I close the modal and open it again, it shows the `Undo` button. It seems it didn't rerender it for the first time but when I close it and reopen it, it shows the `Undo`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In react, updating state is asynchronous. Updated value is only available during the next render. This means updating & then console logging will give you the old state. So for fixing this you need to re render using UseEffect hook in React. Using following code page will be re render when there is change in audioDeleted state value. This code needs to be add in index.js file.

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(audioDeleted);
ShowEditConfirmation();
},[audioDeleted])
```

I hope this may fix your issue. Please let me know.

Comment: It has nothing with the `asynchronous` concept since I'm clicking the `Apply Changes` button after clicking the `Delete` button after some seconds but again I can't get the new value of `audioDeleted`. So it seems that the `content` that is being sent to ShowModal doesn't change and rerender. I don't know why.

Comment: No actually we can't get updated value of state before render. So first we need to re render using useEffect hook when our state update. You need to add this code in index.js 
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(audioDeleted);
ShowEditConfirmation();
},[audioDeleted])

In useEffect you will get updated state value. so here you need to call showEditConfirmaton() which will update the Content. Please check and let me know. This works for me.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to check it but the `ShowEditConfirmation` function has a parameter `post`, how can I pass it there?

Comment: You don't need to pass post as parameter. You can use new state selectedPost for managing post. This is the working example you can check here and let me know if any help needed. https://playcode.io/1528582

Comment: @kodfire https://playcode.io/1528582

Comment: Thank you very much @RiyaMeghnani, it worked. The next problem is that what if I have some other SHOWs similar to `ShowEditConfirmation` like `ShowReport` but it is out of the scope of this question and I will fix it myself. Thanks again!